# how to find out a browser supports web fonts or not using javascript?

Tags: javascript, webfonts

I just want a piece of code to check whether a browser supports CSS3 web-fonts or not.
for example I have a font which by the size of 12px looks too small so I have to set it on 16px but if the page is viewed with a browser without webfonts support the text looks too big.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) for this: [@font-face detection docs](http://www.modernizr.com/docs/#fontface).

Answer (score 1):

This article by Remy Sharp has given me the best success. Plus you get to use Comic Sans.
http://remysharp.com/2008/07/08/how-to-detect-if-a-font-is-installed-only-using-javascript/

The basic idea here us using Comic Sans with a huge font size as the fallback for the font you want to detect. Because CS is such a wide font, if the font you are detecting is not install, the div will be wider then expected.